# How to group HTML elements by wrapping using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML, that I can not change. I can only change the CSS and Javascript. I have HTML with spans and a lot of dl lists.

But, now I want to wrap this HTML. I want to have a div around it. But I want a div to the groups. A group begins with the first span and ends with the last dl.

How can I do this with Javascript / jquery?

```
<span>Information</span>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<span>Specifications</span>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<span>Product information</span>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
<dl></dl>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through each `span` and wrap elements from this **until** next `span`. If there is no `nextUntil()` span, it will select all following siblings in the DOM:

```
$('span').each(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('span').addBack().wrapAll('<div />')
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7rUK/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrapAll()` function. See here examples and documentation: https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: That is a great function but the OP is asking how to wrap around 1st span and last dl,or before next span.

Comment: Yeah that is my question. I already read the wrap functions in jquery. But that is not the solution.